# Get Resource (in project root path) from jar file

Tags: java, jar, path, resources, inputstream

I want to read a text file (input.txt) from within my running jar.

I did read a lot of similar questions, but none of them could help me with my specific problem.

The folder structure is something like that:

D:\Users\Nathaniel\git\projectfolder\src\main\java\folder1\folder2\files.java

My input.txt file is in the projectfolder.

And the main method is the files.java.

I did play around with all kinds of solutions:
for example:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Or:

```
Enumeration<URL> en = getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResources("");
        List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("vor while");
        if (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("in while");
            URL url = en.nextElement();
            JarURLConnection urlcon = (JarURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
            try (JarFile jar = urlcon.getJarFile();) {
                Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String entry = entries.nextElement().getName();
                    System.out.println(entry);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a solution that works when I run the program from eclipse AND the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your file in a resource folder (src/main/resources)? That way you could retrieve with:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/input.txt")));
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? That the input.txt lies in the same folder as the jar file, but not in the jar file? The code should work on many diffrent computers.